# How can I make the chapter titles smaller to match the size of the title and abstract pages?

Tags: titles

This is what I have so far in the main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=160mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\pagestyle{plain}
\frenchspacing

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{C:/Users/deepw/Desktop/university/tfg/images/}}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\title{Thesis Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{Day Month Year}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\input{abstract}

\chapter*{Dedication}
To mum and dad

\chapter*{Declaration}
I declare that..

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
I want to thank...

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{introduction}

\chapter{Chapter Two Title}
\input{chapter02}

\chapter{Chapter Three Title}
\input{chapter03}

\chapter{Chapter Four Title}
\input{chapter04}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{conclusion}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\input{appendix}

%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

... and this is how my title page looks like:

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}  
        \vspace*{10mm}
        
        \huge       
        \textbf{Thesis Title}
        
        \vspace{5mm}
        \LARGE
        Thesis Subtitle
        
        \vspace{15mm}
        
        \textbf{Author Name}
        
        \vfill
        
        Trabajo de fin de grado...
        
        \vspace{8mm}
        
        %\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{ceulogo.jpg}
        
        \vspace{8mm}
                
        \Large
        Department Name\\
        University Name\\
        Country\\
        Date 
        
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Commands like \large, \huge, etc make it really easy to size everything, but I don't know how to apply it to the chapters, sections and subsections.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do it with the `titlesec` package.

Comment: Thank you, Bernard! I'm looking at the titlesec documentation atm, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use it, since I am quite new to LaTex. 

Is there a way to write some stuff in the preamble that will apply the correct format to all the titles in the document?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid not. In titlesec, there a simple use, described in the `Quick reference` section, and the more powerful `\titleformat`, described in the `Advanced Interface` section. If you have any difficulties, you can post a (complete) code of what you've tried and ask for help.